# get full name of the AD domain\initials powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have some powershell script which gets the owner of certain files like so:

```
$CreationOwner =Get-Acl $path | Select-Object Owner
```

but now I have the AD name like so `domain\ar` is there anyway to now turn this into the name of the person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ADSI ([Active Directory Service Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170(v=vs.85).aspx)) to retrieve the full name of a domain user:

```powershell
([adsi]"WinNT://$domain/$user,user").fullname
```

In your case:

```powershell
$domainUser = (Get-Acl $path | select -expand Owner) -replace '\\', '/'
$fullUserName = ([adsi]"WinNT://$domainUser,user").fullname
```